# Web UI regression testing for AngularJS-based web applications

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ui-testing

In a recent AngularJS-based job interview, the client discussed the need for Web UI regression testing.

The client briefly presented a scenario where they had rolled out a last minute  DOM change to production, but it turns out that the new button they added was causing some issues on the page (I believe the exact issue was that the new button was getting hidden, but no one caught the issue ahead of time).

The main thing that came out of the conversation was that it would be great if I could come up with a **Web UI regression test that compares old UI with new UI**.

Not being a regression testing expert myself, I seek some advice regarding the best UI testing tools.

Having some AngularJS experience, my first approach would be to use ***Protractor*** - which I know is based on ***Selenium WebDriver***.

I've also come across some Visual UI regression tools such as https://github.com/garris/BackstopJS, http://screenster.io/ , and https://www.parasoft.com/capability/web-ui-testing/ .

So my main question here is for the AngularJS testing folks: What would be the best solution to test for DOM changes in an application ?

I apologize ahead of time if this question is too vague, but I am seeking advice on the best approach for UI Regression Testing.

thank you in advance...

Bob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took sometime to answer this one as I feel this is important and your client's scenario is pretty much valid and happens in real time. I hope this would clear out some concepts regarding web UI testing & automation.

I am assuming that you are aware that why and how the DOM changes.It is mostly due to changes in javascript functions or ajax calls which happen rapidly that our test scripts trying to locate Web Elements might not catch them in that specific time window leading to the famous **Stale Element Exceptions**. Now let us focus on how this happens in the background -

[image]
As you can see the DOM structure above, everytime a webdriver instance/session is created a reference of the web elements is stored which is in turn stored as JSON ref and passed to selenium webdriver and Protractor which is built on top of it.This drives the browser as we see in browser testing and automation.

When a browser refreshes, navigates or reloads, the DOM tree gets destroyed and recreated again, hence every reference to this DOM element become invalid. Element references could be lost or broken in that specific time frame and thus we get the stale element exceptions.

To be honest avoiding these scenarios is not possible and the worst part is it might not happen as often, So how do we tackle this annoying scenario? There are quiet a few work arounds to catch them efficiently-

- To recreate entire reference hierarchy in catch block and call the same method recursively until maximum tries or unbound until some another exception.
- To reference the element locators as a String rather than referencing them using the WebElement because Strings do not go stale.

Both of the above methods are discussed in detail in the following links please go through them as I do not want put code in this post just to keep it simple for understanding concepts.

http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.in/2012/06/staleelementexception.html
http://www.assertselenium.com/java/what-is-staleelementexception-in-webdriver/
http://softtechlabs.com/2015/09/deal-with-staleelementreferenceexception/

I hope this clears out many things for you!

Answer (score 1):

I would vote for use of protractor. You can have test cases that include testing of control states so in the example you mentioned if you have a test that verified when the button was supposed to be enabled and another when disabled (or displayed/not displayed), it would have failed.